# Laravel schedule operation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Cron tasks has it's own scheduler: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/scheduling
and I just wondering is it possible somehow to achieve similar effect to run some task every 5 minutes ( wihout overlaping ) when calling command from command. For example:

Task1 is called every 1 minute:

`$schedule->command('Task1')->everyMinute()`

In this Task1 command I would like to call command Task2 every 5 minutes.

`$schedule->command('Task2')->every5Minute()`

Would it work having in mind that only Task1 is registered in Console/Kernel.php and Task2 is called from Task1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call a command from another command and it will be executed immediately when the first command is ran. See [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/artisan#writing-commands)

However, scheduling a command from another command is not possible.